# Can I connect +5V GND in reverse to get -5V? Why not?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator

Since voltage is relative, if I have a +5V regulated source in my circuit board and need -5V some where, what will happen if I just connected the +5V supply connections in reverse?

Note that the +5V is as an example only.

Comment: Your circuit must have a single reference somewhere (often misleadingly called ground, despite it not being connected to the Earth). If your supply is +5V with respect to your reference, you cannot get -5V, because that would imply moving your reference to the other supply terminal, thus making everything -5V. There are ways to make bipolar voltages from a single DC supply, however.

Comment: Why can't the -5v device use the +5v a the return path i e ground

Comment: Can you draw a schematic of what you are trying to do? I think as you attempt that, it should become self evident why this doesn't work. But to answer your question, in order for one net to act as a return path for voltage of the opposite polarity, it would have to conduct current in both directions simultaneously, which is impossible.

Comment: In some cases you can. For example, some kinds of isolated switching power supplies can simply be connected with positive output to circuit ground, and the negative output will produce a negative supply for the circuit. So you need to be more specific (by showing a schematic) for us to say whether you can or can't do this in your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can! If you have an **isolated** part of circuit which needs GND and -5V, just connect its GND to your +5V and its -5V to your GND, and you'll be fine.

However, if you need +5V somewhere in your circuit and -5V somewhere else within the same circuit, you effectively require 10V between these two points. That's why a single 5V supply will not be enough in a general case.

Comment: When, exactly, would this be applicable? ... If the circuits are isolated, would this ever happen on a diagram or in practice?

Comment: @nickcarraway I do this all the time with batteries or isolated AC-DC wall-warts when I need a quick and dirty negative voltage. Batteries are technically isolated power supplies unto themselves after all.

Answer (score 5):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV4J6Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figures 1, 2 and 3.*

Your understanding is correct. Provided the outputs are isolated (they aren't connected through ground, for example) they can be considered as being similar to batteries. Where you connect the ground is a matter of choice. For dual-rail supplies they can be connected as shown in Figure 3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft6bug.png)</sup>

*Figure 4. A dual rail PSU circuit build with positive voltage regulators. (Decoupling capacitors not shown.)*

Note that this PSU has isolated secondary windings.

Link: [Voltage and current regulators](https://sound-au.com/articles/vi-regulators.html) (Elliott Sound Products, https://sound-au.com).

Answer (score 3):

You are proposing to do something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZLuiC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, you might notice what happens at the common ground - the +5 + and - get tied together and the power supply gets shorted. If R2 is floating, of course, this will work fine, but that is very unlikely. It is exactly the same as taking R2 and connecting it "backwards".

Answer (score 2):

If you reverse the whole thing, you can get -5V everywhere. If you need +5V and GND and -5V, you'll need to do something else.

Comment: Why not reverse the connections for one circuit component only?

Comment: This is where the schematic would help. You need to think of all the connections between that component and other components on different voltage levels.

Comment: You mean the output of this device shall only generate negative voltage? Is that all?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is two wires with potential difference of 5V. Which one you'll call GND and which one + or minus is completely up to you, and has no physical meaning.

But if you bring in some equipment that already has defined GND, than you have to be careful. In example, if you take a power supply, you can treat red and black input however you like in your circuit. But if you're gonna use an oscilloscope in the same circuit you better make sure that GND of power supply and GND of oscilloscope are on the same spot or you'll pluck out your fuses and, depending on where you live, burn down the house :)

Comment: I would emphasis that, only when the negative of the power supply is Earth referenced, then only you need to br careful when hooking up something like an oscilloscope. But when using a battery you can put the Oscilloscope ground anywhere you want. It's all about closing of the circuit. No current will flow if the circuit is not closed.